# Tick checkboxes in bindView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I'm trying to tick checboxes in the rows, where retrieved parameter equals to "1" in CustomCursorAdapter:

**UPDATED:**

```
public ImageCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to);
        this.layout = layout;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.cursor = cursor;
        itemNames.clear();
        for (int x = 0; x < this.getCount(); x++) {

            itemNames.add(x, null);
        }

        Log.d("111adapter", "itemNames Array in ImageCursorAdapter at start = " + String.valueOf(itemNames));

        itemChecked.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.getCount(); i++) {

            itemChecked.add(i, false);
        }

        Log.d("111adapter", "itemChecked Array in ImageCursorAdapter at start = " + String.valueOf(itemChecked));

    }



    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("rentities_description")));

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        String iconname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("rentities_icon"));

        Log.d("111adapter", "iconname in ImageCursorAdapter = " + iconname);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(iconname);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        final CheckBox cBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        final int pos = cursor.getPosition();

        Log.d("111adapter", "pos in ImageCursorAdapter = " + String.valueOf(pos));

        final String entity_title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("rentities_code"));

        final String checked = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("rentities_checked"));

        Log.i("111adapter", "In ImageCursorAdapter: " + entity_title + " = " + checked);

        if (checked.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

        Log.i("111adapter", "trying to check...");
        cBox.toggle();

        //cBox.setChecked(true);

        }
        cBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                    itemChecked.set(pos, true);
                    itemNames.set(pos, entity_title);
                } 

                else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
                    itemChecked.set(pos, false);
                    itemNames.set(pos, null);
                }

            }
        });
        cBox.setChecked(itemChecked.get(pos));

    }

    public static ArrayList<Boolean> getSetOfCheckedItems() {
        Log.d("111adapter", "itemChecked in ImageCursorAdapter in the end = " + String.valueOf(itemChecked));
        return itemChecked;
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> getSetOfItemsNames() {
        Log.d("111adapter", "itemNames in ImageCursorAdapter in the end = " + String.valueOf(itemNames));
        return itemNames;
    }
```

But none of this methods has led to result:

```
cBox.toggle();
cBox.setChecked(true);
```

Logs show that `checked` == '1' in some rows and this is correct.

```
09-15 11:14:42.965: I/111adapter(21749): In ImageCursorAdapter: CH01 = 1
09-15 11:14:42.965: I/111adapter(21749): trying to check...
```

nothing happens...

Comment: Are you sure? Would be nice to see code with only one of these methods as you might be switching them on and then off instantly.

Comment: if you remove the line `cBox.setChecked(itemChecked.get(pos));`, does it help?

Comment: @IvanFazaniuk see the answer for the proper solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Try not to define checkBox directly by findViewById
First declare widgets in this way

```
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}
```

Secondly in newView define them like this :

```
@Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        // Inflates the list item layout.
        final View itemLayout =
                mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_item, viewGroup, false);
        // Creates a new ViewHolder in which to store handles to each view resource. This
        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text1 = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        holder.text2 = (TextView) itemLayout.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.img);

        // Stores the resourceHolder instance in itemLayout. This makes resourceHolder
        // available to bindView and other methods that receive a handle to the item view.
        itemLayout.setTag(holder);

        // Returns the item layout view
        return itemLayout;
    }
```

and finally in bindView you can access them by

```
 final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
  holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd do

```
itemChecked.set(pos, checked.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
```

instead of

```
    if (checked.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
        Log.i("111adapter", "trying to check...");
        cBox.toggle();
   }
```

because in the end you use this list to set the checked state:

```
cBox.setChecked(itemChecked.get(pos));
```